# Dynamic Spring bean creation

Tags: spring, cdi, inject

I'm using an API that exposes services in the form of XXXLocalServiceUtil classes which are static wrappers of singleton objects. Instead of using the static XXXLocalServiceUtil methods I want to inject the XXXLocalService objects themselves to use them directly in my code, e.g.:

```
@Named
public class MyMailingService {        
    @Inject UserLocalService userService;

    public String mailUser(String email) {
       User user = userService.getUser(email);
       emailUser(user);
    }
}
```

And configure my `applicationContext.xml` like so:

```
<beans ...>
    <bean class="x.y.z.UserLocalServiceUtil" factory-method="getService"/>
    <bean class="x.y.z.CompanyLocalServiceUtil" factory-method="getService"/>
    ...
</beans>
```

This works perfectly. Now, this API I'm talking about has about 100 of these XXXLocalServiceUtil classes, each with their own static `getService` method which returns the actual service. Instead of listing all those services in my `applicationContext.xml` I would like to let Spring do the magic of finding the right XXXLocalServiceUtil class for each XXXLocalService I inject. So what I need is some kind of dynamic bean factory that will do the work for me, on a lazy-loading basis of course.

Anybody knows how this can be achieved easily?

Comment: have you tried to put _@Autowired_ instead of _@Inject_, and define your xml to autowire by type?

Comment: I think you can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programatically-to-spring-web-app-context).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a **GenericApplicationContext** to dynamically load the beans to an applicationContext along with the rest of your spring beans declared in xml.  Here is an example implemented using the [Reflections library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/)...

```
private static final Pattern SERVICE_UTIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*LocalServiceUtil.*");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().addUrls(
            ClasspathHelper.forPackage("x.y.z"))
            .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false));
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(builder);
    GenericApplicationContext applicationContext = new GenericApplicationContext();
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

    for (Class<? extends Object> serviceUtilClass : classes) {
        String className = serviceUtilClass.getName();

        if (SERVICE_UTIL_PATTERN.matcher(className).matches()) {
            GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
            beanDefinition.setBeanClassName(className);
            beanDefinition.setFactoryMethodName("getService");
            beanDefinition.setLazyInit(true);

            String beanName = StringUtils.uncapitalize(serviceClass.getSimpleName().replace("Util", ""));
            applicationContext.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
        }
    }

    XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(applicationContext);
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions("classpath:/applicationContext.xml");
    applicationContext.refresh();
}
```

**Update:**  To use this in a web application, you can simply extend Spring's **XmlWebApplicationContext** and override the `initBeanDefinitionReader` method as follows...

```
private static final Pattern SERVICE_UTIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*LocalServiceUtil.*");

@Override
protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(
        XmlBeanDefinitionReader beanDefinitionReader) {
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().addUrls(
            ClasspathHelper.forPackage("x.y.z"))
            .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false));
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(builder);
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = beanDefinitionReader.getRegistry();

    for (Class<? extends Object> serviceClass : classes) {
        String className = serviceClass.getName();

        if (SERVICE_UTIL_PATTERN.matcher(className).matches()) {
            GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
            beanDefinition.setBeanClassName(className);
            beanDefinition.setFactoryMethodName("getService");
            beanDefinition.setLazyInit(true);
            String beanName = StringUtils.uncapitalize(serviceClass
                    .getSimpleName().replace("Util", ""));
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
        }
    }
}
```

}

and add the following `context-param` to your **web.xml**...

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>x.y.z.MyXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Wonderful! Now how can I load this GenericApplicationContext in my webapp at deploy time? Do I have to write a custom ContextLoader or is there an easier option? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can now comment :)  Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could try is to change `@Inject` to `@Autowired` and define in your applicationContext.xml to autowire by type, like this:

```
<beans ... default-autowire="byType">
    ...
</beans>
```

`@Inject` and `@Autowired` are equivalent, but Spring's `@Autowired` annotation has the advantage to have the *required* attribute to be mandatory injected.

**Another solution:**

Instead of using factories, you can use beans with the scope **prototype**.

Your `XXXLocalService` must implement the `ApplicationContextAware` interface, and get the prototyped bean through it, i. e. :

```
@Named
public class MyMailingService implements ApplicationContextAware {        
    @Inject UserLocalService userService;

    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.appContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public String mailUser(String email) {
       User user = (User) appContext.getBean("user");
       emailUser(user);
    }
}
```

And your applicationContext.xml looks like:

```
<beans ...>
    <bean id="user" class="x.y.z.User" scope="prototype"/>
    ...
</beans>
```

With every invocation of `getBean()` you'll get a new object of that type, with the benefits of injecting everything in that bean.

Comment: Hmm I can't really use autowire-by-type because Spring has no idea where to find an instance of e.g. the `UserLocalService` type (it doesn't know it has to be constructed from the `UserLocalServiceUtil` factory class). The second suggestion is not really an option, because I want to remove as much plumbing as possible, not add more. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then inject your XXXLocaServiceUtil instead of XXXLocalService, or use the scope prototype

Comment: I don't want to inject XXXLocalServiceUtil, because it's a class with only static methods that, in the background, calls the same methods on XXXLocalService in a non-static way. This is a limitation of the API I'm using, so I can't change this fact.

Comment: define one new bean for each XXXLocalServiceUtil in your applicactionContext.xml with the name XXXLocalService ,the attribute factory-bean referencing XXXLocalServiceUtil and the attibute factory-method moved from XXXLocalServiceUtil to this bean. Hope this work for you

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing now. But because there is 100+ of such XXXLocalServices, and all factory methods have the same name, I wondered if there were an easy way to define these beans on a "dynamic" basis, without having to list each and every one of them.