# How to programatically add beans in Java to the app-context.xml in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, applicationcontext

I was following this tutorial http://java-diaries.blogspot.com/2011/03/get-started-with-spring-jms-using.html and I do not understand why for an @Service and an @Autowired annotation you need to explicitly create beans in the app-context.xml but for the @Component, it creates one for you. Can someone explain this? Also, is there a way to add the destination and connectionFactory beans using annotations? Or do i need a solution along the lines of [Add Bean Programmatically to Spring Web App Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programatically-to-spring-web-app-context)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `context:component-scan` tag, classes annotated with both @Component and @Service will be detected and don't need to be declared in your application context.

@Autowired is different.  When you declare a field @Autowired, it means that the bean that's in the app context -- whether declared explicitly or picked up by the component scan -- is injected.