# Get Camel route information from Endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, spring-jms

I am creating a JMS route programatically by following code :

```
from("jms:queue:OUTBOUND_QUEUE?concurrentConsumers=5&messageListenerContainerFactoryRef=msgListenerContainerFactory").processRef("mqprocessor");
```

I have class :

```
public class MessageListenerContainerFactoryImpl implements MessageListenerContainerFactory {

        @Override 
        public AbstractMessageListenerContainer createMessageListenerContainer( 
                        JmsEndpoint endpoint) { 
        } 
}
```

I want to exchange some information/parameter between the above route and endpoint. And based on the parameter value I want choose the connection factory to be set in this message listener container.

Please let me know if I was able to explain my problem statement.

Is there any other way to achieve this? I want build connectionfactory at runtime and so do route.
Is there any method in JmsEndpoint which I can leverage to know route-id?

Answer (score 0):

I would create such a route in a method, supply the MLC as a parameter, then when needed, remove that route gracefully and recreate it with new parameters. Changing the parameters does not really make much sense.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Peter. I have question, JMS route just takes spring bean reference and not object reference, so how should I be passing MLC as parameter? Could you please elaborate with some example. 
Also in above case, MLCFactory would be invoked at time of route initialization. All I am trying to understand in from JmsEndpoint is  which route has called invoked this method so that I can reply with appropriate MLC object. My MLC would change based on which route is invoking it.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are up to by setting MLC at runtime, but anyway - yes - they have to be in the Camel registry, which in your case seems to be the spring context.

Here is some info on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programatically-to-spring-web-app-context