# How Inject in Spring org.apache.http.client.HttpClient?

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` client reference in my `HttpServiceClientImpl` Class.

```
public class HttpServiceClientImpl implements  HttpServiceClient {

private HttpClient client;

public void createFooStuff(){
 client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

}
```

in `createFooStuff HttpClientBuilder.create().build()` returns `org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient Abstract Class`

How Can I put in `applicationContext` for this injection???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4540762/755183

Comment: Please post your Spring configuration.