# Why is programmatically created bean not available in the application context

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring 3.0.7 application, in which I have to initialize some beans in Java rather than xml. I'm trying to figure out why the beans I initialize can't be retrieved from the application context.

When the below code executes, I get "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'beanName' is defined" when I call beanFactory.getBean("beanName").

```
public class BeanToCreateBeans implements ApplicationContextAware {
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        BeanObject bean = new BeanObject();
        beanFactory.initializeBean(bean, "beanName");
        System.out.println("bean in the application: " + beanFactory.getBean("beanName"));
    }
}
```

Why can't the bean be retrieved after creating it? I need to be able to create the bean and add it to the application context.

**Update**: As the answer states, my code isn't actually registering the bean, which answers the question I posed. So, in order to make my code work the way I wanted, it looks like:

```
public class BeanToCreateBeans implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry bdr) throws BeansException {
        BeanDefinition definition = new RootBeanDefinition(BeanObject.class);
        bdr.registerBeanDefinition("beanName", definition);
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        BeanObject bean = new BeanObject();
        beanFactory.initializeBean(bean, "beanName");
        System.out.println("bean in the application: " + beanFactory.getBean("beanName"));
    }
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add how you are creating that bean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Bean Programatically to Spring Web App Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programatically-to-spring-web-app-context)

Comment: Just as you see in the code - creating a POJO and then initializing it in the beanFactory.

Comment: That isn't registering the bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AutowireCapableBeanFactory#initializeBean(Object, String)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#initializeBean-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-) doesn't add a bean to a context or bean factory. The javadoc states

> Initialize the given raw bean, applying factory callbacks such as
>   setBeanName and setBeanFactory, also applying all bean post processors
>   (including ones which might wrap the given raw bean).

It basically just processes the object you pass to it as if it was a bean initialized as part of the `ApplicationContext`. Notice that the method returns an `Object`, the result of the initialization.

> **Returns:**
>   the bean instance to use, either the original or a wrapped one