# How to create a bean by type in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

In my ApplicationContext I have several Beans being created the same style. So I have a lot of dublicated code writing a `FactoryBean` for each of this beans. Those beans have a common ground, implementing all one special interface.

I would like to move all that bean creation to one factory. That one would have to provide a methode like this

```
<T extends CommonInterface> T createInstance(Class<T> clazz);
```

There I could implement all the instantiation necessary to create one of my special beans.

My implementation would be called by spring for

```
@Autowired
private MyCommonInterfaceImplementation impl;
```

in that way

```
createInstance(MyCommonInterfaceImplementation.class)
```

So far I looked at `BeanFactory` and `FactoryBean`, both seem not to be I'm searching for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you not using the `@Component` annotation?

Comment: @MartinFrey, how component annotation helps in this case? May be I'm fully understand question but in this case I this case annotation is not a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use [@bean](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwj_m_nY3PrOAhVJvo8KHe9VA4cQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.spring.io%2Fspring-javaconfig%2Fdocs%2F1.0.0.M4%2Freference%2Fhtml%2Fch02s02.html&usg=AFQjCNEXWiDDGZQ2ae9di_LjsYmAMIzEsQ&sig2=IDiGavRMSgyPqstWjOsUiw&bvm=bv.131783435,d.c2I)

```
@Bean
public MyCommonInterfaceImplementation getMyCommonInterfaceImplementation(){
    return MyBeanFactory.createInstance(MyCommonInterfaceImplementation.class);
}

//should autowire here
@Autowired
private MyCommonInterfaceImplementation impl;
```

Comment: OK, it's far better than implementing everytime a FactoryBean. But I have something about 30 Beans leading to 30 @Bean methods doing all the same. Having the ability to create a bean by its class would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need the `@Bean` annotation on a "factory" only if you need some special handling during the creation of a bean.

If everything can be `@Autowired`, either by setters, fields, or one constructor, and nothing else needs to be done on a bean during initialization, you can simply declare the annotation `@Component` on each implementation of your interface. This works as long as you have `component scanning` active inside your application. The result will be that for each component spring will create a bean which you can use.

I'm writing this on a mobile so showing code is not the best. Just follow some tutorial on `@ComponentScan`, or if you need, let me know and I can augment this answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring 4.3 you no longer have to annotate your bean classes and you can let them be instantiated via a componentscan.

`@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        value = "some.package.path",
        includeFilters = {
                @Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {
                        MyClass1.class,
                        MyClass2.class,
                        MyClass3.class
                })
        })`

This actually creates beans for the three classes listed there. The example should work without filters as well (everything in the package becomes a bean). This works as long as the classes have a single constructor that can be used for autowiring. I don't think it is possible to filter for all implementations of a particular interface and then register a bean.

To do that, you might do something with a `ContextListener` and e.g. use reflection to find out what classes to instantiate and then use context.autowire(..) to inject any dependencies from your context. A bit hacky but it might work.

`@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
   ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
MyClass bean
   =  context
       .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
       .autowire(MyClass.class, Autowire.BY_NAME.value(), true);
...
}`

That still leaves the problem of how to get the bean registered in the context of course.

You might also be able to adapt the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programatically-to-spring-web-app-context) on how to add beans programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the best approach I've found is using a `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`. As example I've used https://github.com/rinoto/spring-auto-mock

But, since it is quite complicated and "too much magic" to create beans from nothing, we decided to explicitly create those beans via `@Bean`.

Thanks for your answers.