# dynamic spring factory to create a bean requested by its given type?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Springframework has a flexible dependency injection mechanism. There are many ways to define beans including FactoryBean where you can create a factory for a specific known type. 
However, what I am looking for is a way to create a factory that gets invoked as fallback if a bean was requested by type but is not present and would result in a no such bean exception. Therefore I would expect an API like `<T> T getObject(Class<T> type)` (while FactoryBean is missing the type). Would I need to implement my own BeanFactory and define as a parent container (sounds awkward and unflexible to use) or what is the best way to solve this? As spring data somehow manages to instantiate any sub-type of Repository this should be possible somehow. I could actually also invent a marker interface where I would derive all my sub-types from.
Background: I would like to support @Inject for any service interface such that I would get a client proxy injected that invokes that service remotely. I already have implemented all the things to create such client (https://github.com/hohwille/oasp4j/blob/develop/modules/service/src/main/java/io/oasp/module/service/common/api/client/ServiceClientFactory.java) manually. Now I just need the missing link to integrate this with spring DI.

FYI: I searched the entire web for this. I found similar or same questions like [How to create a bean by type in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348010/how-to-create-a-bean-by-type-in-spring) but no (real) answers.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188724/parametrize-bean-factory-by-type-in-spring-boot (also without answers). I'll keep looking.

Comment: I created a JIRA issue for this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15883