# Cassandra session null at runtime

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following problem: i want to make a list of Cassandra templates starting from a list of sessions. However the problem is that at runtime i get that the session oject is null.
The code i use is the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class KeyspaceSession {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("cluster")
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("converter")
    CassandraConverter converter;


    public List<CassandraOperations> getTemplates(){
        List<CassandraOperations> listOfTemplates = new ArrayList<>();
        for(CassandraKeyspaces keyspace : CassandraKeyspaces.values()){
            CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
            session.setCluster(cluster.getObject());
            session.setKeyspaceName(keyspace.getKeyspace());
            session.setConverter(converter);
            session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS); 
            CassandraOperations op = new CassandraTemplate(session.getObject());
            listOfTemplates.add(op);
        }
        return listOfTemplates;
    }

}
```

I get the following answer from the server:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1505204641753,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
  "message": "Session must not be null",
  "path": "/getUser/10/pl"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CassandraSessionFactoryBean` requires initialization after you've set all properties. Call `CassandraSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()` before obtaining the `Session`. You also need to clean up sessions on application shutdown.

Ideally, you would register `BeanDefinition`s for each `Session` and `CassandraOperations` bean you want to create.

References:

- [Add Bean Programmatically to Spring Web App Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programmatically-to-spring-web-app-context)
- [How to Create Your Own 'Dynamic' Bean Definitions in Spring](https://dzone.com/articles/how-create-your-own-dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Spring before so forgive me if I'm missing something. But I don't see that you set any contact points so how will the driver know what cluster to query?

Try this:

```
cluster.setContactPoints(<cassandra_server_ip>);
```

Comment: I have a configuration class that does that, this is why i am injecting the cluster and the converter:

Comment: The idea is that i want to generate the templates and the sessions dinamically and cycle through them and use the appropriate one depending on the requiest. So far i was only able to have more sessions by making multiple templates in the Configuration class however now i want to generate the session and the corresponding template dinamically by reading the keyspaces from a properties file.

Comment: Okay I understand better now. However this goes beyond my knowledge, hope someone else can help you.