# how to create N number of Kafka Template dynamicaly at run time - spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a spring boot application that needs to connect N number of Kafka clusters. based on some condition Kafka template need to switch and send a message

I have seen some solutions to create separate Kafka template beans but in my use case number of clusters will change at the deployment time

ex:

```
@Bean(name = "cluster1")
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplatesample1() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(devProducerFactory1());
}

@Bean(name = "cluster2")
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplatesample2() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(devProducerFactory2());
}
```

is there any other solution for this? if you can share a sample code its much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that each cluster can be described with the following attributes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class KafkaCluster {
  private String beanName;
  private List<String> bootstrapServers;
}
```

For example, two clusters are defined in the `application.properties`:

```
kafka.clusters[0].bean-name=cluster1
kafka.clusters[0].bootstrap-servers=CLUSTER_1_URL
kafka.clusters[1].bean-name=cluster2
kafka.clusters[1].bootstrap-servers=CLUSTER_2_URL
```

Those properties are needed before beans are instantiated, to register `KafkaTemplate` beans' definitions, which makes `@ConfigurationProperties` unsuitable for this case. Instead, [Binder API](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#configuration-property-binding) is used to bind them programmatically.

`KafkaTemplate` beans' definitions can be registered in the implementation of [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html).

```java
public class KafkaTemplateDefinitionRegistrar implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

  private final List<KafkaCluster> clusters;

  public KafkaTemplateDefinitionRegistrar(Environment environment) {
    clusters= Binder.get(environment)
        .bind("kafka.clusters", Bindable.listOf(KafkaCluster.class))
        .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
    clusters.forEach(cluster -> {
      GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
      beanDefinition.setBeanClass(KafkaTemplate.class);
      beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(() -> kafkaTemplate(cluster));
      registry.registerBeanDefinition(cluster.getBeanName(), beanDefinition);
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
  }

  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory(KafkaCluster kafkaCluster) {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(
        ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        kafkaCluster.getBootstrapServers());
    configProps.put(
        ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(
        ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
  }

  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(KafkaCluster kafkaCluster) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory(kafkaCluster));
  }
}
```

Configuration class for the `KafkaTemplateDefinitionRegistrar` bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaTemplateDefinitionRegistrarConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public static KafkaTemplateDefinitionRegistrar beanDefinitionRegistrar(Environment environment) {
    return new KafkaTemplateDefinitionRegistrar(environment);
  }
}
```

Additionally, exclude `KafkaAutoConfiguration` in the main class to prevent creating the default `KafkaTemplate` bean. This is probably not the best way because all the other `KafkaAutoConfiguration` beans are not created in that case.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Finally, below is a simple test that proves the existence of two `KafkaTemplate` beans.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class SpringBootApplicationTest {
    @Autowired
    List<KafkaTemplate<String,String>> kafkaTemplates;
    
    @Test
    void kafkaTemplatesSizeTest() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(kafkaTemplates.size(), 2);
    }
}
```

For reference: [Create N number of beans with BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462889/create-n-number-of-beans-with-beandefinitionregistrypostprocessor), [Spring Boot Dynamic Bean Creation From Properties File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161636/spring-boot-dynamic-bean-creation-from-properties-file)