# How to create and use beans from Command Line Argument in SpringbootApplication and use them?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, command-line-arguments, javabeans

I am trying to create a batch job using ApplicationRunner in my sprinbootApplication and I want to use the command line arguments as variables in my code.
So i want to extract the command line arguments, make beans from them and use them in my code. How to achieve it ?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySbApp implements ApplicationRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Myclass.class, args);
  }

  @Autowired
  private Myclass myclass;

  @Override
  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    String[] arguments = args.getSourceArgs();
    for (String arg : arguments) {
      System.out.println("HEYYYYYY" + arg);
    }
    Myclass.someMethod();
  }
}
```

How do I create beans here ?

Comment: Could you please describe the problem you're trying to solve? Why would you need to create beans at runtime, based on input arguments? Couldn't those arguments instead be parameters to a call on a preexisting bean?

Comment: `Myclass` is a class! ... `myclass` is an instance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assume:

```java
// class ...main implements ApplicationRunner { ...

// GenericApplicationContext !!! (but plenty alternatives for/much tuning on this available):
@Autowired
private GenericApplicationContext context;

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
  String[] arguments = args.getSourceArgs();
  for (String arg : arguments) {
    System.out.println("HEYYYYYY" + arg);
    // simple sample: register for each arg a `Object` bean, with `arg` as "bean id":
    // ..registerBean(name, class, supplier)
    context.registerBean(arg, Object.class, () -> new Object()); 
  }
}
// ...
```

Then we can test, like:

```java
package com.example.demo; // i.e. package of main class

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

// fake args:
@SpringBootTest(args = {"foo", "bar"})
public class SomeTest {

  // the "testee" ((from) spring context/environment)
  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext ctxt;

  @Test
  public void somke() throws Exception {
    // should contain/know the beans identified by:
    Object foo = ctxt.getBean("foo");
    assertNotNull(foo);
    Object bar = ctxt.getBean("bar");
    assertNotNull(bar);
  }
}
```

or just like:

```
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("foo")
  Object fooBean;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("bar")
  Object barBean;

  @Test
  public void somke2() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(fooBean);
    assertNotNull(barBean);
  }
```

Refs:

- dynamic beans:

  - [Add Bean Programmatically to Spring Web App Context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4540713/592355) (2010)
  - [How to register bean dynamically in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57157396/592355) (2019)
  - [How to add bean programmatically to Spring context?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43021493/592355) (2017)
  - https://medium.com/@venkivenki4b6/spring-dynamically-register-beans-in-4-ways-at-run-time-c1dc45dcbeb9
  - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-beans
  - [`GenericApplicationContext` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html)
- testing:

  - [How do you pass program arguments in a @SpringBootTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42377254/592355)