# Can we change @Component name runtime / dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ioc-container, spring-annotations

```
public abstract class Vehicle{
    private String vehicleName;
    
    public class Vehicle(String vehicleName){
        this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
    }

    public void drive();
}

@Component("Car")
public class Car implements vehicle(){
    
   public Car(String carName){
       super(carName);
   }

}
```

Here, My requirement is i want to set object name dynamically, i.e. as per above code, my reference to **Car** class is going to the name which i pass to **@Component**, and i want reference to **Car** class to be **carName** property from **Car** class.

Kindly suggest if it is possible or not.

Note - I dont want @Component name to be from any properties file, i want it from my existing car object.

Comment: No you cannot. Also what would be the purpose? Also why is `Car` even a component...

Comment: You cannot change the component name at runtime. You could use FactoryBeans, but I'm not sure what you want to accomplish with your code, so let me ask: can you please add some details? What's the matter you want to address, in this case?

Comment: What is exactly your use case?

Comment: You can dynamically add a bean to Spring with a name that you choose. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540713/add-bean-programmatically-to-spring-web-app-context

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, the short answer is 'NO'.

What you need to understand is `@Component` will creates a singleton bean, which will be initialized when the application context startup (unless you lazy initialize it). So you cannot really create a spring bean whenever you want.

Also note that these singleton beans should be `stateless` (only state they have is a shared state).

Since you haven't provide what is your real requirement, I suggest you to look at this [bean scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) documentation. It might be useful to you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The "@Component" is a Spring concept to create a reusable and injectable component to another (and whatever) Spring Bean.

It should not be used for a POJO.

Comment: i think he is just learning with some tutorial, seems he is not considering the class as a pojo.

Answer (score 0):

`@Component` is to detect the custom beans, in your which is registering the component with Car as name, so as it is became a reference you are not allowed to change the Component name in runtime.